# jquery "fixed" mouse position

Tags: jquery, mouse

I am using the following code to get the mouse position:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) { mouseY = e.pageY; });
```

What I want to achieve is to get the X coordinate relative to the window, that means
that clicking on the top left corner, even if scrolled, should give 1 instead of, for example, any other bigger number, given by the scroll. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the y-coordinate relative to the document, then just subtract [`$(window).scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) from that to get the y-coordinate relative to the window.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) { 
    var mouseY = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`pageY` gives the position of the event relative to the page, while `clienty` gives it relative to th viewport. So for your purpose, you need to use `e.clientY`. Have a look at the article by [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1869-jQuery-Mouse-Events-PageX-Y-vs-ClientX-Y.htm).